# Track click event through socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a `node.js` application with express and `socket.io` to track click event from users .. my code snippet is

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/user.html');
});

app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/admin.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('clicked', function(val){
    io.emit('clicked', val);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
</style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click">Click Me</button>

    <script>
          var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
          var count = 0;
          $('#click').click(function(){
            var val = count++;
            socket.emit('clicked', val);
             });
    </script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

admin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Total no. of clicks</h2>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('clicked', function(val){
            console.log(val);
            $('#message').text(val);
        });
    </script>


<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

All I want to do is display no. of clicks on the admin page in realtime

Error I got in admin page through console is
[image]

Comment: put you javascript after two libraries

Answer (score 1):

//Put your javascript code below these two libraries

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('clicked', function(val){
            console.log(val);
            $('#message').text(val);
        });
    </script>
```